AWS Fargate ResourceInitializationError
I get the error "ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: The task cannot pull registry auth from Amazon ECR: There is a connection issue between the task and Amazon ECR. Check your task network configuration. RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://api.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 13.234.9.96:443: i/o timeout"
What am I doing wrong? APIServiceSecurityGroup allows egress on all protocols and all ports implicitly. My CloudFormation below
P.S. I don't want public ips on my ECS fargate service
  APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DependsOn:
      - MainVPC
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-load-balancer-security-group
      GroupName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-load-balancer-security-group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 443
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 443
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-load-balancer-security-group
      VpcId: !Ref MainVPC
  APILoadBalancerSecurityGroupEgress1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
    DependsOn:
      - APIServiceSecurityGroup
      - APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref APIServiceSecurityGroup
      FromPort: 6544
      GroupId: !Ref APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 6544
  APIServiceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DependsOn:
      - MainVPC
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-service-security-group
      GroupName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-service-security-group
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-service-security-group
      VpcId: !Ref MainVPC
  APIServiceSecurityGroupIngress1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    DependsOn:
      - APIServiceSecurityGroup
      - APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      FromPort: 6544
      GroupId: !Ref APIServiceSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 6544
  CommonECSTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      RoleName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-common-ecs-task-execution-role
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-common-ecs-task-execution-role
  CommonECSTaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      RoleName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-common-ecs-task-role
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-common-ecs-task-role
  APILoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    DependsOn:
      - APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-load-balancer
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref APILoadBalancerSecurityGroup
      Subnets: !If
        - !Ref ZoneAPublicSubnet
          !Ref ZoneBPublicSubnet
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-load-balancer
  APITargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    DependsOn:
      - MainVPC
    Properties:
      HealthCheckPath: /health
      HealthCheckPort: 6544
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTPS
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-target-group
      Port: 6544
      Protocol: HTTPS
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-target-group
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref MainVPC
  APILoadBalancerHTTPSListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn:
      - APITargetGroup
      - APILoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:ap-south-1:710035641090:certificate/0c7854ff-ce25-453f-8468-05b067564921
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref APITargetGroup
          Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref APILoadBalancer
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
  APITaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    DependsOn:
      - MainRepository
      - CommonECSTaskExecutionRole
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        # - Image: !Sub ${MainRepository.RepositoryUri}/${Env}.api.latest
        - Image: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${AWS::StackName}-main-repository:${Env}.api.latest
          Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 6544
      Cpu: !If
        - ProdEnv
        - 1024
        - 256
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref CommonECSTaskExecutionRole
      Memory: !If
        - ProdEnv
        - 1024
        - 512
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      RuntimePlatform:
        CpuArchitecture: ARM64
        OperatingSystemFamily: LINUX
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-task-definition
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref CommonECSTaskRole
  APIService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn:
      - MainCluster
      - APITargetGroup
      - APIServiceSecurityGroup
      - APITaskDefinition
      - APILoadBalancerHTTPSListener
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref MainCluster
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api
          ContainerPort: 6544
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref APITargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref APIServiceSecurityGroup
          Subnets:
            - !Ref ZoneAPublicSubnet
              !Ref ZoneBPublicSubnet
      ServiceName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-service
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-service
      TaskDefinition: !Ref APITaskDefinition


Your other option is a NAT.

You either need to add a bunch of VPC endpoints to the VPC so that things like ECR can be accessed from inside the VPC, or you need to add a NAT Gateway to the VPC so that your tasks can connect to things that exist outside the VPC. As of now your tasks have no access to anything outside of the VPC, so services like ECR are unreachable.

@MarkB My service runs in a public subnet. Do I still need a NAT?

Running in a public subnet without assigning a public IP address means the service can never access the Internet. You would have to either enable public IP addresses, so the service can connect to the Internet, or move the service to a private subnet, and add a NAT Gateway in the public subnet. Or as I said, you could add a bunch of VPC endpoints for the various AWS services.
